# PDF invoice shows a empty invoice

Tags: invoice, pdf

When i want to print an PDF invoice, the only thing i see is al empty invoice with no tekst, only the layout and my logo.

Can anyone tell me how i can fix this ?

Comment: how high is your php memory limit? you can try to increase it.

Comment: anything in magento logs or server logs (make sure logging is enabled)?

Answer (score 1):

You should check out this article http://www.sweet-apple.co.uk/fixing-problems-with-magento-creating-empty-invoice-pdfs/ . Seems like the same issue, may be due to a problem with text encoding.

Comment: Thank you Micheal, but it doesn's work. Any other options ? The invoice shows in the send mail but not in the print pdf.

Comment: Have you taken a look at your PHP memory limit as simonthesorcerer recommended?